# How to display current and old information for WordPress in Email message

Tags: php, wordpress, discord, profile, zapier

I'm currently programming a service that sends out an Email, when an user updates his/her profile. This information will be displayed as a Discord Message (integration via Zapier).
My question, my current setup only displays the old information, how can I get the newest & older version being sent out?. If I apply the same code at my profile page I do get the 'latest' version.

So the problem I currently have: `$discord_username` is the previous data, instead of the up to date variant. The `$user_info_old / $user_info_old->discord_id` is empty, and if I `print_r($olduserdata)` then I just get a `1` back.

The  how can I get the current information for `$user_info->discord_id` and the previous data for `$user_info->discord_id`? This is my current setup. Not the nicest, but it does the job for 90%.

````
function user_profile_update( $user_id, $olduserdata ) {
    $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
    $active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_info, $args );
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_info_old = get_userdata( $olduserdata );
    $discord_username = $user_info->discord_id;
    
    if ($active_memberships && $discord_username) {
      $namemembership = $active_memberships[0]->plan->name;
      $user_regdate = date( 'm/d/Y h:s', strtotime( $user_info->user_registered ) );
      $to = 'xxxxx@zapiermail.com'; 
      $subject = $user_info->discord_id;
      $message = "**Name: **".$user_info->user_firstname." ".$user_info->user_lastname. "\n**Email Address: **" .$user_info->user_email. "\n**Membership: **".$namemembership."\n**Registered: **".$user_regdate." UTC\n".$user_info_old->discord_id."Please make sure to add correct permission and remove verified tag. \nDiscord ID:```".$user_info->discord_id."\n```".$user_info_old->discord_id."```";
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
    } 
    clean_user_cache( $user_info );
}
````

**Update**
I've tried various caching methods, but nothing sofar. + as a bonus: the message tends to display twice. Is this function/hook being called twice normally?

Comment: The variable `$olduserdata` should contain the old information, and the call to `$user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );` should be getting you the new information. If the latter isn't working, there's a chance that a cache might be in the way, although WordPress does explicitly try to clear the user cache. When you diff the two variables, what do you see?

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for responding. I've reformatted my question, and tried various caching methods, but nothing sofar. Does my question makes more sense now? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have time to write a full example, unfortunately, but I think the problem is that `discord_id` is a dynamic property which incurs a database lookup and you are in a weird state at that point. Instead, I'd recommend looking at [`insert_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/insert_user_meta/) which happens _before_ the update. This will allow you to perform additional database queries as needed, hopefully. It is a filter, so make sure to return the first parameter regardless.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for responding. I'm not much further sadly. Would appreciate if you can have a look. If not, I understand.